# Display a picture uploaded to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a user profile picture in a ASP MVC5 project. I have added a page that is called `changepicture.cshtml` and will display the current user's picture.

I have an upload function that will take a picture someone uploads like `hank.jpg` and rename it to that `users_id.jpg`.

For example:

> System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_9C8230B38B954135385F2B0311EAC02ED8B95C4D504F8424BA3ED79B37F0AAAF.jpg

I would like to display each users individual picture in the page by grabbing there user id and adding .jpg, how would I do this?

changepicture.cshtml

```
@model KidRoutineLogging.Models.ChangePictureViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Picture";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

<h4>Your Current Picture  : @Html.ViewBag.CurrentPicture</h4>

<img src="@Url.Content("~/uploads/hank.jpg")" />

<br />
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
        //string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
        //Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, filename));

        Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, user + ".jpg"));
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Your path should be `Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, user.Id + ".jpg"));`.  I'm not 100% which part is the issue?  Displaying the picture or saving the picture with the user id as part of the file name?

Comment: My issue is displaying this uploaded file.

<img src="@Url.Content("~/uploads/userid.jpg")" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a funky-typed name for your file because you are attempting to cast an entire class (object) to string.  Additionally, if you are wanting to name the file "UserId.jpg", your code is doing more work than it should.

This line:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Can be simplified to this line:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

That would leave your final code as:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
        Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, userId + ".jpg"));
    }
    return View();
}
```

You could get rid of the userId variable completely, and update your SaveAs method to

```
Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, User.Identity.GetUserId()+ ".jpg"));
```

Also - you really should decorate this ActionResult with the `<HttpPost>` attribute since it should only be handling the POSTing of the form and not associated with a GET request.

Comment: I made this change, but how would I grab the userid in the cshtml page and display the picture?

Comment: Exactly the same way.  `<img src='@Url.Content(string.Format("~/uploads/{0}.jpg", User.Identity.GetUserId())' />`.  Alternatively calculate the url for the image in the controller and pass it to the view via the View Model.

Comment: With this I get error no definition for GetUserId(), does something need to be added to use this function?